# A more reliable move_uploaded_file check?

Tags: php, file-upload

So I'm building an ajax + php file uploader.

At the end of all the checks, as usual, I've got this code:

```
if(!move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile)){
  header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
  $response = array (
    'status'    => 'error',
    'file_link' => $targetFile
  );
} else [...ok...]

[...]

echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

It does upload the file is `$targetFile` is correct. The problem is the opposite: `move_uploaded_file` will always return true, even if I set `$targetFile` to 'WTF'..

So my ajax program is not receiving errors when the target dir is wrong or not writable. So, is there eny better method to check if a file was really uploaded after executing `move_uploaded_file()`?

Comment: It appears that `WTF` *is* writable though…!?

Comment: Setting the target file as `wtf` means its writing it to the default path php uses, which must be allowed for writing to not throw an error. Is there any reason why you would not be in full control of the `$targetFile` path/name??

Comment: You can also use `is_dir()` and `is_writeable()` before trying to move the file if you, for some reason, wouldn't know what folder it's saved in or it's permissions  (which you should know).

Comment: I didn't know it would have uploaded to a non existent directory. Quite strange to me. Anyway, that's it. Ok I just have to do some more manual checks. Thank you

Comment: Well. The directory exists. You may want to dig around in your server and look for where that `wtf` filename got placed :) For me, for example, it would have saved that at docroot.

Comment: yes you're right

Comment: just check `if(file_exists('path_to_file/filename.ext'))` at your target destination after moving it.